# copy/paste values based on header name macro

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, copy-paste, vba

I have used this macro successfully in another file, but when I moved the macro to a different file with the same worksheet references, it will not run. When I "debug" the code, they have highlighted the "**Set src = Sheets("SIS Data Original")**" as the problem. Do you have any idea why this might be or how I can fix it? I am open to rewriting the code if necessary.

Thanks!

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim col As Long
Dim src As Worksheet, Dst As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Set src = Sheets("SIS Data Original")
Set Dst = Sheets("SIS + Excel Data")
For x = 1 To 50
col = Application.Match(src.Cells(1, x), Dst.Rows(1), 0)
src.Columns(x).Copy
Dst.Cells(1, col).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `1` What is the error message that you are getting? `2` Does the workbook where you are running this code from has `Sheets("SIS Data Original")`

Comment: Yes, the new file has the tab "SIS Data Original". And the error I'm getting is "Subscript out of range (Error 9)"

Comment: `Subscript out of range` on that line says it all :) That means either there is a spelling mistake in that sheet name or that sheet is missing in "Activeworkbook"

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you for your help!